# closing keyboard on click of outside edittext in android issue

Tags: android

**What i have::**

- I have two containers each of them have a edittext Widget
- When i click the edit text the keyboard popps up
- I want to close the edit text on focus changed from the editText(if i
  click outside the edit text)

**What is happening**:

- Edittext is not closing

*This problem is not there in case of single container, How can i resolve this*

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    FragmentTransaction ft;
    Fragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Load header and body fragment to the container
        ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragHeader = ContainerOne.newInstance(); 
        Fragment fragBody = ContainerTwo.newInstance();  

        //Header
        ft.replace(R.id.containerOne, fragHeader, ContainerOne.class.getSimpleName());
        //Body
        ft.replace(R.id.containerTwo, fragBody, ContainerTwo.class.getSimpleName());
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ContainerOne.java**

```
public class ContainerOne extends Fragment {

    EditText editText1;


    public static ContainerOne newInstance(){
        Log.d(ContainerOne.class.getSimpleName(), "newInstance");
        ContainerOne fragment = new ContainerOne();
        return  fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Make sure the keyboard only pops up when a user clicks into an EditText
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); 

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_one, container, false);
        editText1=(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    hideKeyboard(v);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
        //Hiding the keyboard onClick of outside the edittext
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =(InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }



}
```

**container_one.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

**container_two:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ContainerTwo.java**

```
public class ContainerTwo extends Fragment {

    public static ContainerTwo newInstance(){
        Log.d(ContainerTwo.class.getSimpleName(), "newInstance");
        ContainerTwo fragment = new ContainerTwo();
        return  fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_two, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this !

### I have added all the code

Comment: what you mean by close edittext ?

Comment: when yu click edittext keyboard pops up ... i want to close the keyboard on click outside the edittext ...when keyboard is popped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a click listener on your container (outside your edit text) and call your hideKeyboard method

Answer (score 1):

Define a method hideSoftKeyboardOnTouch() in your utility class or main activity only(which ever suits you) as shown below. Its is preferred to define it in a utility class as it may be used from different classes(as i did in my project).

```
public static void hideKeyboardOnTouch(final Activity activity, View view) {

    // Set up touch listener for non-text box views to hide keyboard.
    if (!(view instanceof EditText)) {
        view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                hideSoftKeyboard(activity);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    // If a layout container, iterate over children and seed recursion.
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);
            hideKeyboardOnTouch(activity, innerView);
       }
    }
 }
```

Set an id to your parent layout(Linear layout in your case) let say id is parent

```
<LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/parent"
  -----
  -----
 </LinearLayout>
```

Then in your main activity onCreate() call this hideSoftKeyboardOnTouch() method passing its context and parent layout id like this

```
hideSoftKeyboardOnTouch(this, findViewById(R.id.parent));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please you have multiple edit text in form then you need to use bellow code.

```
 edtText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                hideKeyboard(view);
            } else {
                showKeyboard(view);
            }
        }
    });

public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
public void showKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view,0);
}
```